# Altura responsiva

Tags: web, responsive

Que tal, estoy trabajando sobre una página web, la cual debe ser forzosamente responsiva, el problema es que con mi diseño, se ve bien en solamente algunos dispositivos, y quiero opiniones sobre como dar altura o como modelar el diseño de mis **div** para que estos sean totalmente responsivos.
El detalle esta en que tengo clases genéricas que uso sobre varias secciones y en esas secciones el texto no es igual, por lo que supongo también genera inconvenientes.
Quisiera ayuda para definir alturas o quitarlas y usar otro tipo de atributos, a continuación dejo el `scss` y el `html`

```
<section class="divided-contact">
<div class="side-right2">
  <div class="side-right-wrapper-contact">
    <form class="contact-form">
      <fieldset class="contact-field">
        <h4 class="contact-h4">Contacto</h4>
        <input class="contact-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre">
        <input class="contact-input" type="text" name="email" placeholder="e-mail">
        <div class="button-division">
          <input  class="contact-phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Teléfono">
          <input class="contact-button" type="submit" name="enviar" value="ENVIAR">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="side-left4">
  <div class="side-left-wrapper4">
    <h2 class="side-left-title4">¿Quieres integrarte a nuestro equipo?</h2>
    <p class="divided-paragraph4">Somos una empresa en crecimiento, joven y muy comprometida, que se inspira y motiva ante nuevos retos; que es conocedora del sector en el que trabaja y de las necesidades de quienes requieren de productos y de un buen servicio competente y comprometido.</p>
    <a href="contact.html">
    <input  class="contact-new-button" type="submit" name="#" value="ME INTERESA">      
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.divided-contact{
  height: 30vw;
  background-color: $blueText;

@include small {
  height: 200vw;      
}

.side-left4{
float: right;
font-family: Raleway-Regular;
position: relative;
width: 50%; 
height: 30vw; 

@include small{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
}

.side-left-wrapper4{       
    color: $blueText;
    width: 68%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    @include small{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0;
  }

  .side-left-title4{
    font-size: 3.6em;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Raleway-Regular;
    color: $white;    
    line-height: 35px;
    width: 60%;
    font-weight: bold;  
    margin-bottom: 10px;  

    @include small{
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
      width: 70%;
    }
  }

  .divided-paragraph4{
  color: $white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Raleway-Regular;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
  width: 75%;

  @include small{
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2.0em;
    }
  }

  .contact-new-button{
    border: 2px solid $white;
    padding: 13px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: $blueText;
    color: $white;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Raleway-Regular;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 20px;

    @include small{
      min-width: 50%;
      font-size: 2.0em;
    }

    &:hover{
      background-color: $white;
      color: $blueText;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-family: Raleway-Semibold;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
}



.side-right2 {
  float: left;
  font-family: Raleway-Regular;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%; 
  height: 30vw;

@include small {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;  
}   }

.side-right-wrapper-contact {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url("../assets/images/Contacto.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;

 @include small{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
 }

 .contact-form{
   height: 100%;      
   padding: 100px 0;

  @include small{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .contact-field{
    background-color: $white;
    font-family: Raleway-Semibold;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;

    @include small{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .contact-h4{
      color: $blueText;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Raleway-Semibold;
      line-height: 24px;
      font-size: 3.0em;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      padding: 12px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .contact-input{
      width: 98%;
      border: 1px solid $grayTitles;
      border-radius: 100px;
      background-color: $white;
      color: $grayTitles;
      font-family: Raleway-Regular;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      line-height: 32px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    .button-division{
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;

      @include small{
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        float: left;
      }

      .contact-phone{
        border: 1px solid $grayTitles;
        border-radius: 100px;
        background-color: $white;
        color: $grayTitles;
        font-family: Raleway-Regular;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        line-height: 32px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 38px;

        @include small{
          width: 56%;
          margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
        }
      }

      .contact-button{
        background-color: $white;
        color: $blueText;
        border-radius: 100px;
        border: 2px solid $blueText;
        font-family: Raleway-Regular;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 15px;
        width: 42%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: auto auto auto 26px;

        @include small{
          width: 40%;
          margin: auto;
        }

        &:hover{
          background-color: $blueText;
          color: $white;
          cursor: pointer;
          font-family: Raleway-Semibold;
          font-weight: bold;
         }
        }
      }        
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Debes explicar bien lo que deseas hacer. Haz una pregunta clara y concreta, no se entiende muy bien por el texto y el código qué esperas obtener y qué es lo que estás obteniendo.

Comment: El responsive **no suele** usarse para ajustar la altura. Es sumamente difícil por no decir imposible que ajustes ancho y alto de una página a cada dispositivo al menos sin usar gran cantidad de CSS y JS para lograrlo, el peso también importa, es por ello que se usa una distribución de contenidos "vertical" desde que apareció la técnica, es decir que tu página no debe nunca hacer un scroll horizontal pero es perfectamente admisible y normal el scroll vertical.